# Unable to change the dbpath in mongodb through mongodb.conf

Tags: exception, boost, mongodb, permission-denied

I am getting the following message
**exception in initAndListen std::exception: boost::filesystem::exists: Permission denied: "/vol/mongodb", terminating**

in /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

ls -al /vol/mongodb  gives -
drwxrwxrwx  2 mongodb mongodb 4096 2011-08-07 12:10 ./

When I change the dbpath, back to the default, which is /var/lib/mongodb - it works fine.

How do I solve this?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using a service to start mongodb? If so, does the owner of the **service** have the correct rights to that folder?

Comment: Yes, I am using the service but how do I check the owner of the service? thanks.

Comment: @cdf No. I tried passing the dbpath argument while starting the server itself and that works so didn't explore more

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem initially and found it was caused by the `mongodb` user not having appropriate permissions on the **parent** directory.

I'd recommend checking `/vol` to ensure that the `mongodb` user can at least read files from that directory.  May also need execute permissions too, and I suspect this will hold for each subsequent parent directory up to root.