# Unable to change dbpath in MongoDB using command line

Tags: mongodb, command-line, cmd

I started learning mongoDB a couple of days ago. Post installation, I am trying to change the dbpath as follows:

```
mongod --dbpath C:\myfolder\myproj\data\db
```

running the above command, I got the below statements in the command line:

Now i typed the below command to check if the dbpath has changed

```
mongod dbpath
```

this line still returns:

C:\data\db

I also tried running the below command to change the dbpath (as mentioned in a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWbMrx5rVBE, but still the dbpath didn't change

```
mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath c:\myfolder\myproj\data\db
```

Can someone tell me how can I change my dbpath?

I looked at the stackoverflow question [MongoDB not using /etc/mongodb.conf after I changed dbpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568997/mongodb-not-using-etc-mongodb-conf-after-i-changed-dbpath) and also [Unable to change the dbpath in mongodb through mongodb.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971634/unable-to-change-the-dbpath-in-mongodb-through-mongodb-conf/11547244) but none of them helped

Comment: does c:\myfolder\myproj\data\db exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run

```
mongod --dbpath C:\myfolder\myproj\data\db
```

You are **starting** an instance of `mongod` with it's data directory as `C:\myfolder\myproj\data\db`

Running a second

```
mongod dbpath
```

is effectively starting a new instance of `mongod` - which, by default, has its dbpath as \data\db

Just run     `mongod --dbpath C:\myfolder\myproj\data\db` as you are, then use `mongo` to connect to it (or whatever client you're using)
When connecting to that instance, you'll be using the instance that is storing it's data in C:\myfolder\myproj\data\db

Comment: Hi Alex, Is there a way to then find the dbpath of that particular instance?

Comment: @RahulSingh see this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39651696/131809 in short, check your task manager and see path to executable